# How can I expand the embedded Facebook post text width in web site?

Tags: facebook, post, embedded-resource

I have a sidebar width of 225 px. The embedded post displays a narrow 1-2 word display.

I have tried finding answer in Facebook help, adjusting width of embed, and scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/:

> *Can I customize how the post is displayed on my web page?*
>
> *Currently, you cannot customize how Embedded Posts are displayed on your page. **The size of the post is fixed to the same dimensions as it's shown on Facebook.***